# Understanding how to determine the probability of failure

Tags: probability

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to identify what the probability of failure for each industrial plant would be based on the type of equipment in the plant. From historical data, each year 2 sites out of 50 suffer a failure do a piece of equipment failing. So in other words each year there is a 0.04 probability that there will be a plant failure.

I found that using logistic regression I was able to create a relationship between the number of plant failures observed vs. the type of design and the age of the facility. This provided me probabilities such as the following below. However, summing all these probabilities add up well beyond the 0.04 failures that should occur per year. How can I interpret the logistic regression probabilities in contrast to the 0.04?

In addition to just the design and age of the plant, the other pieces of equipment have probability of failures. For instance lets say the plant has three pieces of equipment each with probabilities of failure of 0.15 and if one piece of equipment fails the plant can still operate, however if the plant is poorly designed like in case C, it may stop operating even with just one failure, thus the design has a influence. Not sure how to tie all this together toward getting to the 0.04 events per year.

For Example:

```
Design  FAIL   AGE  Probability
A       1      34     0.92
B       1      23     0.93
C       0      43     0.23
B       0      54     0.34
A       1      55     0.93
```

Comment: How are using logistic regression exactly? On what data? Looking at the table I see that you are using some examples of failures (or not) based on the total life of a plant. But the 0.04 empirical probability you mention, is the **per year**.

Comment: I am also not sure how you understand regression. You seem to think that if you add up the probabilities that regression gives you, you'll end up with the empirical average probability of failure. Maybe you could expand on your understanding of what regression does, so we can respond appropriately.